# react: изменение содержимого строки в зависимости от значения переменной

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, строки, reactjs

Подскажите как более правильно, корректно и красиво в React сформировать значения некоторых атрибутов

Конкретно у меня стоит задача выставить для элемента `<li>` дополнительно класс `active` если задана переменная

Я делаю так:

```
<li className = {"nav-item nav-link" + ((params.isActive === true) ? " active" : "")} id = {params.id}>{params.title}</li>
```

Но как по мне, получается очень топорно - дополнительный плюс чтобы склеить строки и т.д.

Подскажите как это нужно делать правильно?

P.S.

как вариант я конечно могу добавить класс "active" после прорисовки элементов, но это еще более неправильно, как мне кажется :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом:

```
const { id, isActive, title } = params; 
const className = `nav-item nav-link${isActive ? ' active' : ''}`;
return <li className={className} id={id}>{title}</li>;
```

Другим решением может стать использование npm пакета [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)

```
import classnames from 'classnames';

const { id, isActive, title } = params; 
const className = classnames('nav-item', 'nav-link', { 'active': isActive });
return <li className={className} id={id}>{title}</li>;
```

Comment: действительно забыл про ``

<li className = {`nav-item nav-link ${(params.isActive === true) ? "active" : ""}`} id = {params.id} key = {index}>{params.title}</li>